# Browser back button is not perform right

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am using Rails and did a navbar. The navbar folds into a burger after the certain width has been reached. I am able to click on the burger-sign without defining any event listener in JS. I just added this into the head of my application.html.erb

```
<meta>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
  <%= yield :js %>
<meta>
```

After adding, the click worked perfectly, but my home link, root_path was broken. It constantly lead to the #index page, but would display only "2019"on the blank page, not the actual #index page layout. I fixed the links adding the get method ty my link, like this:

```
<li><%= link_to 'Home', root_path, method: :get %></li>
```

What still doensn't work, is my browser back button, this still leads to this weird blank page with the 2019 printed on it. Can someone explain what is happening and how do I get to the previous page by clicking on the browser back button? Thanks!

P.S. This is the sourse html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Neigbornow</title>
  <meta name="csrf-param" content="authenticity_token" />
  <meta name="csrf-token" content="RST7jzlY6IftapnMzEI9BkObFqh4B8EaX4cnX7PavwQq7ziZ5PKkVtgnExe8oShZxl56m40/UBgYG0OacVrWbg==" />

  <meta>
  <script src="/assets/jquery3.self-e200ee796ef24add7054280d843a80de75392557bb4248241e870fac0914c0c1.js?body=1"></script>
  <script src="/assets/jquery.self-bd7ddd393353a8d2480a622e80342adf488fb6006d667e8b42e4c0073393abee.js?body=1"></script>
  <script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.self-784a997f6726036b1993eb2217c9cb558e1cbb801c6da88105588c56f13b466a.js?body=1"></script>
  <script src="/assets/bootstrap/affix.self-b2bd74404ab3c627c5129dcdd3bdc2fc0a9d4bff4e1b6f1bae96412f9a1e9723.js?body=1"></script>
  <script src="/assets/bootstrap/alert.self-7c7aa23778284da0e4aa395a0a6d858c7efd891c9312fe71908b28292654ac0c.js?body=1"></script>
  <script src="/assets/bootstrap/button.self-b7a8ce9f47662b97ab74ef3dd416e93d3a4f644b252307a28231976a0149feef.js?body=1"></script>
  <script src="/assets/bootstrap/carousel.self-c2c0ad2347d3fdd8447abd9d5792efed40ad5afadc5e0de3001e34904a6f68ce.js?body=1"></script>
  <script src="/assets/bootstrap/collapse.self-4db094cc14a1aafa93e51e6f298115323037bb9e24c060dd0de52f27446f6227.js?body=1"></script>
  <script src="/assets/bootstrap/dropdown.self-7efa4aa654357ae664a98ec52151c25cd4927eacd1fabe038d068d9344b62cbd.js?body=1"></script>
  <script src="/assets/bootstrap/modal.self-4ca048907279f4bb9187ba2541ae5d03296917d5c42e8fef0b58ec31c8902f0f.js?body=1"></script>
  <script src="/assets/bootstrap/scrollspy.self-e62629e47ba5fe8b7faaa745f2fef2ccdb1bfd56ffb4f95615684ef40c74bcc4.js?body=1"></script>
  <script src="/assets/bootstrap/tab.self-7fbfa844201ceeb4b896e4d185a33df19a284fe461281b7c0f78dbea2ef6da5a.js?body=1"></script>
  <script src="/assets/bootstrap/transition.self-3c74f1999fcbf39cfb240b67c9a9e900863859f82f53fb27e5a388fe5e1a1c5c.js?body=1"></script>
  <script src="/assets/bootstrap/tooltip.self-82858d5843f55bfed321ea59fc5b180f3d2a8afc498ebc4d665561110b807875.js?body=1"></script>
  <script src="/assets/bootstrap/popover.self-a1e6d4555fb912f0405099135eaddbe8273ba8f08323477a471d34419d57b446.js?body=1"></script>
  <script src="/assets/bootstrap-sprockets.self-fbfa5ad7d9aa0afe439ec4ff3883acc4cb92b62cb67c40d674320c9aa1d4642d.js?body=1"></script>
  <script src="/assets/activestorage.self-1ed4604ac2170045f1ffca4edb81a75246661555e4f9cf682bb8a21825e32e1c.js?body=1"></script>
  <script src="/assets/turbolinks.self-569ee74eaa15c1e2019317ff770b8769b1ec033a0f572a485f64c82ddc8f989e.js?body=1"></script>
  <script src="/assets/action_cable.self-69fddfcddf4fdef9828648f9330d6ce108b93b82b0b8d3affffc59a114853451.js?body=1"></script>
  <script src="/assets/cable.self-8484513823f404ed0c0f039f75243bfdede7af7919dda65f2e66391252443ce9.js?body=1"></script>
  <script src="/assets/home.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1"></script>
  <script src="/assets/profile.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1"></script>
  <script src="/assets/reviews.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1"></script>
  <script src="/assets/user_steps.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1"></script>
  <script src="/assets/users.self-877aef30ae1b040ab8a3aba4e3e309a11d7f2612f44dde450b5c157aa5f95c05.js?body=1"></script>
  <script src="/assets/application.self-813dac1f9eb54ab17313987648014af35d74ebeb15c2265509c52491183d3dcc.js?body=1"></script>

  <meta>




  <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/style.self-67cdb30c3f83239515cab5c4f35c9f7533c426bd77b8d75c40e8ff613eb658ec.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="/assets/application.self-fe639f1da8d2570340060e10dc6bf2430bb27ff5e40357dce724cbc8efb24584.css?body=1" data-turbolinks-track="reload" />
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
        <div class="navbar-brand pull-left" href="#">
          <img src="/assets/logo_transparent-ad9441c50046e461177bad078050d5345754d0413d7ef8a7f549aa5bf35e466e.png" width="147" height="70" class="d-inline-block align-left mr-2">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
          <li><a data-method="get" href="/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a>About</a></li>
          <li><a>Search</a></li>
          <li><a>Contact</a>

            <li>
              <div class="log-in-btn"><button class="btn" type="submit"><a href="/user/sign_in">Log in</a></button></div>
            </li>
        </ul>

      </div>
      <!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </nav>




  <div class="container">


  </div>

  <head>
    <title>Neignbornow</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="empty-space"> </div>


    <div class="site-blocks-cover overlay" style="background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1464082354059-27db6ce50048?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2850&q=80);" data-aos="fade" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-center justify-content-end text-center">




          <div class="row justify-content-center mb-4">
            <div class="col-md-8 text-left">
              <div class="site-intro">

                <h1>Home is about personal connections, not just neighbors.</h1>
                <p>Recconect with your neighbors, by sharing things and experiences. Now.</p>
                <button class="btn register" type="submit"><a href="/user/sign_up">Register</a></button>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Header -->

    <!-- About section -->


    <div class="site-section bg-light">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="col-12">
          <h2>About Neighborheart</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu,
            pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt.
            Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut
            metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing
            sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt.
            Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- About section -->



    <!-- Testimonials -->

    <div class="site-section bg-white">
      <div class="container">

        <div class="row justify-content-center mb-5">
          <div class="col-md-7 text-center border-primary">
            <h2 class="font-weight-light text-primary">Testimonials</h2>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="slide-one-item home-slider owl-carousel">
          <div>
            <div class="testimonial">
              <figure class="mb-4">
                <img src="images/person_3.jpg" alt="Image" class="img-fluid mb-3">
                <p>John Smith</p>
              </figure>
              <blockquote>
                <p>&ldquo;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur unde reprehenderit aperiam quaerat fugiat repudiandae explicabo animi minima fuga beatae illum eligendi incidunt consequatur. Amet dolores excepturi earum unde
                  iusto.&rdquo;</p>
              </blockquote>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div class="testimonial">
              <figure class="mb-4">
                <img src="images/person_2.jpg" alt="Image" class="img-fluid mb-3">
                <p>Christine Aguilar</p>
              </figure>
              <blockquote>
                <p>&ldquo;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur unde reprehenderit aperiam quaerat fugiat repudiandae explicabo animi minima fuga beatae illum eligendi incidunt consequatur. Amet dolores excepturi earum unde
                  iusto.&rdquo;</p>
              </blockquote>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div>
            <div class="testimonial">
              <figure class="mb-4">
                <img src="images/person_4.jpg" alt="Image" class="img-fluid mb-3">
                <p>Robert Spears</p>
              </figure>
              <blockquote>
                <p>&ldquo;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur unde reprehenderit aperiam quaerat fugiat repudiandae explicabo animi minima fuga beatae illum eligendi incidunt consequatur. Amet dolores excepturi earum unde
                  iusto.&rdquo;</p>
              </blockquote>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div>
            <div class="testimonial">
              <figure class="mb-4">
                <img src="images/person_5.jpg" alt="Image" class="img-fluid mb-3">
                <p>Bruce Rogers</p>
              </figure>
              <blockquote>
                <p>&ldquo;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Consectetur unde reprehenderit aperiam quaerat fugiat repudiandae explicabo animi minima fuga beatae illum eligendi incidunt consequatur. Amet dolores excepturi earum unde
                  iusto.&rdquo;</p>
              </blockquote>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



    <!-- Testimonials -->


    <!-- Search section and show map -->

    <div class="site-section bg-light">
      <div class="container">


        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12">
            <h2 class="h5 mb-4 text-black">Search for items in your neighborhood</h2>


            <!-- Serach bar -->


            <div class="form-search-wrap mb-3" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="200">
              <form method="post">
                <div class="row align-items-center">
                  <div class="col-lg-12 mb-4 mb-xl-0 col-xl-4">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control rounded" placeholder="What are you looking for?">
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-12 mb-4 mb-xl-0 col-xl-3">
                    <div class="wrap-icon">
                      <span class="icon icon-room"></span>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control rounded" placeholder="Location">
                    </div>

                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-12 mb-4 mb-xl-0 col-xl-3">
                    <div class="select-wrap">
                      <span class="icon"><span class="icon-keyboard_arrow_down"></span></span>
                      <select class="form-control rounded" name="" id="">
                        <option value="">All Categories</option>
                        <option value="">Real Estate</option>
                        <option value="">Books &amp; Magazines</option>
                        <option value="">Furniture</option>
                        <option value="">Electronics</option>
                        <option value="">Cars &amp; Vehicles</option>
                        <option value="">Others</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-12 col-xl-2 ml-auto text-right">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block rounded" value="Search">
                  </div>

                </div>
              </form>
            </div>

            <!-- Search bar -->


            <!-- Map -->

            <!-- Map -->



          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Search section Search section and show map -->

    <!-- Cathegories -->

    <div class="site-section" data-aos="fade">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center mb-5">
          <div class="col-md-7 text-center border-primary">
            <h2 class="font-weight-light text-primary">Popular Categories</h2>
            <p class="color-black-opacity-5">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="overlap-category mb-5">
          <div class="row align-items-stretch no-gutters">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 mb-4 mb-lg-0 col-lg-2">
              <a href="#" class="popular-category h-100">
                <span class="icon"><span class="flaticon-car"></span></span>
                <span class="caption mb-2 d-block">Services</span>
                <span class="number">1,921</span>
              </a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 mb-4 mb-lg-0 col-lg-2">
              <a href="#" class="popular-category h-100">
                <span class="icon"><span class="flaticon-closet"></span></span>
                <span class="caption mb-2 d-block">Events</span>
                <span class="number">2,339</span>
              </a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 mb-4 mb-lg-0 col-lg-2">
              <a href="#" class="popular-category h-100">
                <span class="icon"><span class="flaticon-home"></span></span>
                <span class="caption mb-2 d-block">Household</span>
                <span class="number">4,398</span>
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 mb-4 mb-lg-0 col-lg-2">
              <a href="#" class="popular-category h-100">
                <span class="icon"><span class="flaticon-open-book"></span></span>
                <span class="caption mb-2 d-block">Books &amp; Magazines</span>
                <span class="number">3,298</span>
              </a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 mb-4 mb-lg-0 col-lg-2">
              <a href="#" class="popular-category h-100">
                <span class="icon"><span class="flaticon-tv"></span></span>
                <span class="caption mb-2 d-block">Electronics</span>
                <span class="number">2,932</span>
              </a>
            </div>

            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 mb-4 mb-lg-0 col-lg-2">
              <a href="#" class="popular-category h-100">
                <span class="icon"><span class="flaticon-pizza"></span></span>
                <span class="caption mb-2 d-block">Beverages</span>
                <span class="number">183</span>
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Cathegories -->


    <div class="newsletter bg-primary py-5">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <h2>Newsletter</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">

            <form class="d-flex">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
              <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" class="btn btn-white">
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>


  <footer class="site-footer">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <h2 class="footer-heading mb-4">About</h2>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident rerum unde possimus molestias dolorem fuga, illo quis fugiat!</p>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-3">
              <h2 class="footer-heading mb-4">Navigations</h2>
              <ul class="list-unstyled">
                <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <h2 class="footer-heading mb-4">Follow Us</h2>
              <a href="#" class="pl-0 pr-3"><span class="icon-facebook"></span></a>
              <a href="#" class="pl-3 pr-3"><span class="icon-twitter"></span></a>
              <a href="#" class="pl-3 pr-3"><span class="icon-instagram"></span></a>
              <a href="#" class="pl-3 pr-3"><span class="icon-linkedin"></span></a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <form action="#" method="post">
            <div class="input-group mb-3">
              <input type="text" class="form-control border-secondary text-white bg-transparent" placeholder="Search products..." aria-label="Enter Email" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
              <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-primary text-white" type="button" id="button-addon2">Search</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row pt-5 mt-5 text-center">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="border-top pt-5">
            <p>
              <!-- Link back to Colorlib can't be removed. Template is licensed under CC BY 3.0. -->
              Copyright &copy;
              <script>
                document.write(new Date().getFullYear());
              </script> All rights reserved | This template is made with <i class="icon-heart" aria-hidden="true"></i> by <a href="https://colorlib.com" target="_blank">Colorlib</a>
              <!-- Link back to Colorlib can't be removed. Template is licensed under CC BY 3.0. -->
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There is no JavaScript or jQuery here

Comment: This is a JS issue

Comment: I see no JS here at all. Please post a [mcve] with client side rendered code. It is not a server side issue so why are we seeing only server side code?

Comment: I do not have a JS code, as I don't know how to correct this behaviour and where. Also, I am in developing phase, so I only work with localhost. What I found for now, that browser cback and forward buttons are the JS Events. My question is, where do I need to integrate the JS code in what code in order to correct this behavior.

Comment: Just added above

Comment: Sorry, I am a beginner. Just copied the sourse, Is this right? Please see above. Hovever ignore the rest of the page, I an just on the navbar roght now. Thanks

Comment: the best would be to edit the snippet I made by clicking edit and then `[<>]` snippet editor. You can edit the snippet now by clicking edit and then scroll down to "edit above snippet"  - if you can just post the HTML you have a problem with together with relevant CDN javascript files (i.e. not your own links since we do not have access to your localhost) and give a step by step of how to recreate the problem, we might be able to help you better

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204135/discussion-between-katharina-schreiber-and-mplungjan).

Comment: `document.write(new Date().getFullYear());` will just replace everything on the document with the current year, if you are using rails use `<%= Date.today.year %>` instead of javascript